# Using Xpath in Selenium to refer to a specific tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Hello I'm getting the error of `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element'` , even though my code seem to be correct and I looked a little bit in stack but I didnt find a solution to my specific problem.
I wanna get the value of the fifth `<p>` set after the `<br>` tag in my html code  , correct me if you see any mistake please.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time

options = Options()

# Creating our dictionary
all_services = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Motif', 'Description'])

path = "C:/Users/Al4D1N/Documents/ChromeDriver_webscraping/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path)

driver.get("https://www.mairie.net/national/acte-naissance.htm#plus")

# We store our 'Motif' & 'Description' for the first link 'acte-naissance'
service = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "section-title").text
desc = service.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='section-group']/p[5]/following::br")
print(desc)
all_services = all_services.append({'Motif': service, 'Description': desc}, ignore_index=True)

# Get all elements in class 'list-images'
list_of_services = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("list-images")

all_services.to_excel('Services.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Can you give the text and/or html code of the section you're looking for?

Comment: I gave the link there , it's mentioned in `driver.get()` , and I want to fifth paragraph content that is set after the `<br>`  in `div class=section-group` , so please just inspect the link there

Comment: I saw the full link, but would rather not search through and count sections, so it would make it a lot easier for me if you could copy and paste the specific section you are looking for.

Comment: <div class="section-group">
       <p>
 <strong>Où doit-on déposer la demande ?</strong><br>
 Lorsque la naissance est survenue en France, la demande doit être adressée à la mairie du lieu de naissance.
 Les personnes nées dans un ancien territoire français ou à l'étranger doivent quant à elles adresser leur demande au service central d'état-civil du ministère des affaires étrangères à Nantes si elles disposent de la nationalité française. Dans le cas contraire, elles doivent prendre contact avec la mairie de leur lieu de naissance ou un consulat de leur pays natal.
 </p>  </div>

Comment: So im interested on the content which is after the <br> tag

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: Are you sure that element is in that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the text you want using this combination:

```py
service = driver.find_element_by_class_name("section-title").text

txt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='section-group']/p[5]").text
desc = txt.split("\n")[1]
```

I also did it with requests and bs4, which is usually a little bit quicker than a headless browser (same issues of scraper navigability):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs

r = requests.get("https://www.mairie.net/national/acte-naissance.htm#plus")
html = Bs(r.text, "lxml")

section = html.find("h1", {"class": "section-title"}).get_text()

div = html.find("div", {"class": "section-group"})
p = div.find_all("p")[4]
p.strong.extract()
txt = p.get_text().split("\t")
desc = (txt[1] + txt[2]).replace("\n", " ")[:-1]
```

Comment: Oh yes it's working , I'm just using selenium since in the project i need to open multiple urls and get elements from them.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `.text` from

```
service = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "section-title").text
```

Comment: the problem is in `desc` content not `service`!

Comment: That is because in desc you try to use find_elements on service, but using ".text" on service line, you assigned a string to service, so it says that string has no find_elements() method!

Comment: Can you just tell me how can I get the value of the content of fifth <p> tag  which it's set after the <br> tag in the <div> class section-group ?